# Best way to solve $\frac{x^3+3}{x^2+1}>\frac{x^3-3}{x^2-1}$

Tags: inequality, fractions, cubics

I was wondering what the best way to solve questions like these are?
$$\frac{x^3+3}{x^2+1}>\frac{x^3-3}{x^2-1}$$
I can get the answer, which is $(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,3)$. But I'm not sure if I have the most efficient method for the final steps. If this didn't involve fractions I'm quite happy sketching a cubic graph and choosing the correct sections. However with the fractional questions, I'm not sure how/if to relate the graph with answer - due to some x values being undefined and if you multiply by a negative then the inequality sign flips.

So far the way I do it is:

1. rearrange until I can solve the cubic - this gives me x=0 as a repeated root and x=3
2. look at the denominators to see where x cannot be defined - this tells me x$\neq$1 and x$\neq$-1
3. list each seperate interval and test them all in the original inequality:

a) $(-\infty,-1)$ trying x = -2 in original inequality tells me this interval works

b) $(-1,0)$ try x=-0.5 this interval does not work

c) $(0,1)$ try x=0.5 this does not work

d) $(1,3)$ try x=2 this works

e) $(3,\infty)$ try x=4 this does not work

So the final answer is: $(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,3)$

Is this the only way to go? Or am I missing something? Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to proceed as follows

$$\frac{x^3+3}{x^2+1}>\frac{x^3-3}{x^2-1}$$

$$\frac{x^3+3}{x^2+1}-\frac{x^3-3}{x^2-1}>0$$

$$\frac{(x^3+3)(x^2-1)-(x^3-3)(x^2+1)}{(x^2+1)(x^2-1)}>0$$

$$\frac{2x^2(x-3)}{(x^2+1)(x^2-1)}<0$$

and from here study the sign of the terms $x-3$, and $x^2-1$ in the
relavant intervals $(-\infty,-1)$, $(-1, 0)\cup(0, 1)$, $(1,3)$, $(3, \infty)$ which leads to the solution $x<-1$ or $1<x<3$.

Comment: I would even go for the five terms $1-2x$, $x-1-\sqrt{2}$, $x-1+\sqrt{2}$, $x-1$ and $x+1$.

Comment: I just realised I wrote -2 rather than -3 in my question! Doesn't really matter, I guess the method is the same.  ( end up with $\frac{-2x^2(x-3)}{(x^2+1)(x^2-1)}$
So when you say study the signs, do you mean separately or all together.
i.e. I know (x-3) is + when x>3, so now I have to look at all the other brackets and see what they are when x>3?

Comment: @basket_case Ah ok I'll revise that. I mean study the sign separetely and then put them togheter using the sign rule in each interval separated by the zeros values.

Comment: Okay that, makes sense and is a bit quicker than my final step. Thank you! Also good to know that I'm not missing some completely different method. I'm just teaching my self some maths for fun so I'm never sure I've missed something.

Comment: @basket_case That's fine, at first I supposed you missed something because your solution was not correct for the first given expression. You are welcome! Bye